# How to setup using boto 2 the lauch configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, autoscaling

I get an error when I use the setup from the boto 2 documentation

The error is an exception that gets thrown saying :

"No default VPC for this user "

From an initial research, it looks like I need to use subnets, but I have a default VPC associated with my account. How can I programmatically setup an launch configuration without a default VPC ? 
For start, I did the following :

```
     #=================AMI to launch======================================================
        as_ami = {
        'id': 'ami-5648a**', #The AMI ID of the instance your Auto Scaling group will launch
        'VpcId' : 'vpc-0c805***',
        'access_key': 'keyFile.pem', #The key the EC2 instance will be configured with
        'security_groups': 'sg-1d83b***', #The security group(s) your instances will belong to
        'instance_type': 't2.micro', #The size of instance that will be launched
        'instance_monitoring': True #Indicated whether the instances will be launched with detailed monitoring enabled. Needed to enable CloudWatch
        }



    autoscaling_group = {
    'name': 'myAG', #descriptive name for your auto scaling group
    'min_size': 1 , #Minimum number of instances that should be running at all times
    'max_size': 1   #Maximum number of instances that should be running at all times
    }

    lc_name = 'myLG' #Descriptive name for your launch configuration

    conn_as = AutoScaleConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)


    lc = LaunchConfiguration( name = lc_name, 
                              image_id = as_ami['id'],
                              key_name = as_ami['access_key'],
                              security_groups = as_ami['security_groups'],
                              instance_type = as_ami['instance_type'],
                              user_data = user_data,
                              associate_public_ip_address=True,
                              instance_monitoring=as_ami['instance_monitoring'])

    conn_as.create_launch_configuration(lc)
```

The error is as follow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createResource.py", line 156, in <module>
    main()
  File "createResource.py", line 122, in main
    conn_as.create_launch_configuration(lc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\ec2\autoscale\__init__.py", line 291, in create_launch_configuration
    Request, verb='POST')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-01-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>No default VPC for this user</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>fac3b7a6-b39c-11e7-b881-75dd83913ada</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a default VPC. If you think you have a default VPC, then the AWS credentials you are using could be for a different account or you are creating in a different region which doesn't have a default VPC.

What are your options?

- Check the region and make sure you create in the correct region
- Check the AWS credentials you are specifying in Boto is for the correct account
- If there is no default VPC, call AWS and restore your old default VPC (or) as John Rotenstein mentioned, [create a new default VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc)
- Specify the subnet id of the VPC in which you want to create your instances

Comment: It is now possible to [Create a New Default VPC using AWS Console or CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html).

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @helloV  How do I associate a launch configuration to a non-default VPC with a subnet ID. Do you mean VPC ID or Ipv4 CIDR ?